# Convergent subsequence extraction

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

We know that if  $f_n$ is a  sequence of measurable functions such that $||f_n||_{L^1} < K$, then there exists a subsequence which converges in the weak topology of $M(\Omega)$ (which is the dual of continuous functions with compact support) and further the subsequence converges in the sense of distribution.

Suppose instead of $L^1$ boundedness, if we have $\int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n =K$ for all $n \in\mathbb{N}$ can we say that there exists a subsequence which converges in the sense of distribution.
I feel this result should be true, but I am unable to prove it. Please help me to prove or disprove

Comment: You certainly need an absolute value sign.

Comment: Why absolute value sign?..  Since integral of each $f_n$ is bounded uniformly they are $L_{loc} ^1$ and hence distributions which are point-wise bounded.

Answer (score 2):

Say  $\int f=0$, and let $f_n=nf$.

Comment: example does not contradict anything as $f_n$ is a $zero-$distribution for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and hence has a convergent subsequence which is the sequence itself, and which converges to $zero-$distribution.

Comment: @Rosy What makes you think that $f$ is the zero distribution if $\int f=0$?

Comment: @Rosy What??? $\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(t)\,dt=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot... :-)

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I found the following result : Let $A \subset D'(\Omega)$
 a set of distributions that is pointwise bounded, i.e. on any fixed
test function $\phi \in  D(\Omega)$ .(which means if $ A = \{T_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ and  $\sup_{\{n \in \mathbb{N}\}}\{|\left(T_n, \phi \right)| <\infty\}$   $\forall \phi \in  D(\Omega) $) Then $A$ is sequentially compact. the sequence with $\int f_n= K$ satisfy the hypothesis isn't it? please correct me if I am wrong.. Thank you

Comment: @Rosy Of course $\int f_n=K$ does not imply that compactness! This seems like you didn't read the answer. Choose $f$ so $\int f=0$, and let $f_n=nf$.

Comment: @Rosy It seems very curious that you're still trying to prove the result in your question after being given such a simple counterexample...